# Visual Studio 2013 - disable auto evaluation of variables on hover

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, evaluation

When debugging in Visual Studio 2013, I have a variable that is around 130MB, and hovering over it even by accident causes my entire environment to freeze and I have to restart the debugging.

I want to disable the auto-evaluation on hover (even if it forces me to use watches to peek a value), but couldn't find it anywhere in the settings.

Is there a way to disable this?